# Photoionization by black-body radiation

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, ionization-energy

I am trying to solve the question:

> "Show that if an atom is photoionized by black-body radiation with the
> temperature $T^*$ such that $kT^*\ll I_H,$ the average kinetic energy acquired by an ejected electron is about $kT^*$."

I understand that the energy of ionizing photon should be equal to the energy differences of the levels in the atom+ kinetic energy of the electron, BUT, I don't understand how to refer to the energy of photons, should it be for each mode or total energy of the spectrum, I'm confused.

Comment: What are $I$ and $H$?

Comment: I_H is the ionization energy of hydrogen

Comment: Are you sure this question is correct? It would make more sense if $kT\gg I_H$.

Comment: why it would make more sense?

Answer (score 3):

The only photons absorbed are those with energies higher than the ionization energy, that is much higher than $k_BT^*$:
$$h\nu = I_H + K > I_H\gg kT^*.$$
In this limit, $h\nu\gg kT^*$ the [Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law) becomes [Wien's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien_approximation):
$$
I(\nu, T)=\frac{2h\nu^3}{c^2}e^{-\frac{h\nu}{kT^*}} = 
\frac{2}{h^2c^2}(I_H + K)^3e^{-\frac{I_H+K}{kT^*}}
$$
Since the exponent drops quickly, we could omit $K$ in the prefactor, giving us essentially an [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) of kinetic energies with mean $kT^*$. (Instead of omitting $K$ in the prefactor, one could try to do some more precise math, but it would produce pretty much the same result. Don't forget to normalize the distribution though.)

Answer (score 0):

Energy Balance: KE of electron = Energy of photon - I.
For all photons with Energy E>I.

I calculated the Energy of the photons above I dividend by the number of photons above I.

Energy of photons above I: Integral over x^3 exp(-x) dx

Number of photons above I: Integral over x^2 exp(-x) dx

Both integrale from I/kT to Infinity. x is the photon energy E/ kT. I skipped the -1 in the denominator of the distribution function because I>>kT.

The normalisation constants area, c, h, pi ... cancel. The result is in units of kT.
I solved it with Wolframalpha.
Result: I (in kT) + 1 + something very small. So the average energy above I is kT. Something small is in the order of 1/I.

Happy Newtonmas.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).